# Turn off marker shadow on vba-generated Excel plots

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm porting some code I use to generate scatter plots in Excel from Win 7 / Excel 2010, to OS X / Excel 2011.  On the Mac, the data points show up with a shadow. I don't want the shadow, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Using [this worksheet](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48901983/shadowOff.xlsm) (it just has random numbers in cells A1:B6 if you don't want to download my macro-enabled worksheet) the following code runs fine, but produces data points with shadows:

```
Sub plotNoShadow()

  Dim x As Range
  Dim y As Range

  Dim cht As ChartObject

  Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6") 'haphazard numbers
  Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B6")

  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=150, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=160)
  With cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        .XValues = x
        .Values = y
        .Format.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse 'This seems to parse, but have no effect
    End With
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
  End With      
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain to me:

1. How to modify this code to remove the shadows, and
2. How it is that this code runs, but setting the SeriesCollection(1).Format.Shadow.Visible to msoFalse manages to run without having any apparent effect?

Per the comment thread below, here's a screencap of the macro output on the left, points with shadow turned on then off in the middle, and shadows turned on on the right. I edited the macro to remove legend and gridlines, for clarity.
It looks like the macro output has less shadow than the 'shadow on' state, but more shadow than the 'shadow off' state.

[image: Screencap to illustrate the three states of shadow existence]

Comment: Are you sure that's shadow and not a 3-D setting?  Try something like `.Format.ThreeD.Visible = False`

Comment: @Tim Williams: Good question Tim. :) However, in MAC switching off the 3-D will still give you the 1st snapshot as in my post

Comment: @Drew Steen: How did you get the middle pic?

Comment: @Siddharth - no mac here to test...

Comment: @Tim Williams: I had a feeling that you didnt have a MAC and hence I said "Good question" I had checked that thing next the moment I checked for the Shadow. And I smiled to myself when you asked that question :) And hence I actually meant it when I said "Good Question" :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I generated the plot using the code in my post, then manually selected the dataset, and turned shadows first on then off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several of the default Chart Styles in Excel that produce a slight 3D effect also have a minor drop-shadow as pointed out earlier.

On my Excel (in Windows 7) the default chart style is 2, so no shadow or 3D effect appears.  I suspect that on the Mac, the default chart style is different.

To fix this, you can set the Chart Style in your code:

```
With cht.Chart
  .ChartType = xlXYScatter
  .ChartStyle = 2
  .....
```

In Excel, the ChartStyle settings have the ability to modify all aspects of the appearance of the chart, including the look of the Marker.  The only thing MarkStyle sets is the shape of the Marker.  All of the other appearance aspects of the Marker are overridden when the ChartStyle is changed.

**EDIT**

The above comments are still basically true, but I have found a way to shut off the shadow.  Like many things with Excel, it is not as easy as you would think.  Setting the visibility property of the shadow has no effect if done in code (for whatever reason), so you need to set the shadow type to "No Shadow".

```
Sub plotNoShadow()

  Dim x As Range
  Dim y As Range

  Dim cht As ChartObject

  Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6") 'haphazard numbers
  Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B6")

  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=150, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=160)
  With cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .ChartStyle = 26 'Something 3D with a default shadow. This line can be left out.
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        .XValues = x
        .Values = y
        .Format.Shadow.Type = msoShadow30 'This is the code for an inner shadow
    End With
  .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
  .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
  End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT Again**

Actually, `msoShadow30` is an "internal shadow" style and may look strange depending on your marker style.  `msoShadow41` is the closest thing to "No Shadow" that I have been able to find.  It's actually the code for shadow below, but by default, it is too faint to see.  If it does show up, the color can always be changed to make it disappear.

Or even better, set the tranparency to 1 (fully transparent):

```
.Format.Shadow.Transparency = 1.0 'Fully transparent
```

Comment: +1 on `.Format.Shadow.Type = msoShadow41` :) (Tested in Excel 2011 ) Adding this line to the code that I gave and changing the `.MarkerSize` to 9 gave the exact image as shown in OP's question. BTW, we have to exclude `.ChartStyle = 26` as you suggested. It gives an altogether different marker

Comment: Nice. For what its worth, just setting .chartStyle to 2 gives me exactly what I was looking for - a plot good for print publication, in which extra visual doo-dads don't help.

Comment: I've found that ".ChartStyle = 2" is sufficient to remove all of the gratuitous shadows, glows, and gradients that are built into the default Mac chart.

Answer (score 2):

The shadow that you are seeing is actually not a shadow. What I mean is that is the default way a marker looks without shadow.

Unfortunately you cannot do much about it. See the snapshots below and you will know what I mean.

**Snapshot:**

[image]

**Alternative:**

You can however play with the marker size to minimize that effect. Try this code.

```
Sub plotNoShadow()

  Dim x As Range
  Dim y As Range

  Dim cht As ChartObject

  Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6") 'haphazard numbers
  Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B6")

  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=150, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=160)
  With cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
        .MarkerStyle = 2
        .MarkerSize = 7
        .XValues = x
        .Values = y
        .Format.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse 'This seems to parse, but have no effect
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow - MS is really doing its best to make it totally impossible to use Excel for publication-ready plots. I thought I had outsmarted them, but apparently not.

Comment: But wait - there must be some way to get rid of the residual shadow. When I manually select the data set, click Format Data Series < Shadow, then select the 'shadow' checkbox to turn shadows ON, then click it again to turn shadows OFF, the shadow is totally deleted. So there must be some other shadow attribute somewhere that can be turned off, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I already checked it :) there is no other attribute for Shadow :) Can you post a sceenshot of what you have now?

Comment: Post edited, with a screencap showing three possible levels of 'shadow-ness'. Is it possible that there are two things which both cast a shadow - the data point, and something else? That would explain how shadows can be on, off, or in-between.

Answer (score 2):

This gratuitous excess formatting in Mac Excel charts has severely hampered conversion of my many programs to the Mac. Fortunately I've discovered:

```
ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 2
```

which applies the default formats without shadows, gradients, and glows. No need to go back and reformat every little detail of every series in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the data series, go to Format Data Series. Under the Shadow option, the "shadow" box will probably be unchecked, right? Check it. That will activate the editing controls underneath. Then set 'transparency' to 100%. And you could also set 'color' to white.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the shadows via the chart legend:

cht.Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(1).LegendKey.Shadow = False

Answer (score 0):

This unruly chart behavior will not be tolerated! Desist shadowy series...

```
With .Shadow
    .ForeColor.RGB = &HFFFFFF
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With
```