# Excel VBA to apply ShapeEffect to a chart series

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have VBA code that I wrote that creates an Excel Column Cluster chart and all of my code works however I am not happy with the look of my chart so I was trying to dress it some. The chart is part of an automated report so I just want to be able to schedule my macro to run and not have to manually make changes to the data series. Because Excel 2007 has the properties and methods of the charts set to read only they don't populate when you record a macro.

So I am trying to do something similiar as the following post 
[How to apply ShapeStyle to a specific Series of a Chart in Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527336/how-to-apply-shapestyle-to-a-specific-series-of-a-chart-in-excel-using-vba)

However I am trying to apply a Shape Effect to a chart series. Manually to get the Shape Effect I want you have to select the series in the chart then Chart Tools > Format > Shape Effects > Preset > Preset 2. This makes the data series appear 3D without the hassle of a 3D chart. Also, I cannot use a 3D chart because I have a fourth data series on a second access and you cannot do this with a 3D column cluster chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

I went back and I looked at this in 2010 to see if anything had changed. You still can't directly apply a preset to a chart however the record macro does make an attempt at recording something.

If you select a series and apply a preset then go look at the 3-D options you can see what values were set. From there it is just a matter of setting those in your VBA.

Here are the classes for the the 3-D options

```
 Selection.Format.Line
 Selection.Format.Fill
 Selection.Format.Shadow
 Selection.Format.Glow
 Selection.Format.ThreeD
```

There are a lot of properties so I won't list them all. I did find that if you record a macro and set a property it gets recorded so that can help you get closer to applying the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of the following attemps:

```
Chart.ApplyLayout(1)
```

using a Diagrammlayoutpreset you previously defined.

Or use this:

```
with Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.ThreeD
     .visible = true  
     .depth = 50
end with
```

Look for the ThreeDFormat-Object in Excel-Help to get all possible settings. This is not 3D-Style-Chart, but 3D-Style series ;) To get the same results as preset2, just lookup the formatchanges in the formatdialog of a preset2-series.

Comment: I have had a lot to do but I will try your suggestions and let you know what I find. I don't know why they didn't make the preset styles like textures.

Comment: Well I finally had a chance to revisit this. Your code does work but doesn't do exactly what I need. Just seems the VBA classes don't include this functionality.